# Moving Content database's from SharePoint 2010 to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: 2010, migration, sql-server, azure, copy

I am working on approaches for moving Content databases from SP 2010 to Azure Blob Storage. Its a lift and shift from SP 2010 to SP 2016 in Azure (eventually). At the moment the content databases needs to be moved to Azure Blob

I have sorted out ways mentioned below.

***SQL Server Import and Export Wizard :*** uses the SSIS to establish connection and move data

***Data Protection Manager :*** This utilizes certificates and network configurations.

***AzCopy :*** Uses Scripts.

Azure Data Factory : Creating Pipeline and transferring data.

Please suggest if there is any other possible approach.

Or which one of these would be the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting to do is not supported. The only supported SQL storage scenarios in Azure are with Azure VMs running SQL Server Standard or Enterprise.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Trevor,  Should I just go with the database attach approach with the Sql Server in SP2016 farm hosted in Azure.

Comment: Provided the farm is in the same region/subnet on Azure, yes you'd just host standard VMs, SharePoint and SQL, in Azure.

Comment: how would I move the content database to the SQL VM though, which approach should I take, any one from the above I mentioned or use any migration query?

Comment: You'd backup the databases and restore them, as if you were moving databases to another SQL Server. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725.aspx